# Is there a way to download AAB or APK from Amazon's Developer Console?

Tags: amazon-appstore

In Google Play I can use the Developer's Console to go back and download any version I've previously uploaded as an AAB or APK.

I can't find something similar on Amazon Developer Console. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the APK/AAB clicking on the rightmost dropdown and then *Download*

[image: Download apk in Amazon Appstore]